# How do you use a range in haskell with a variable distance between elements

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I have the following code snippet started, and i'm not sure where my error(s) are. The goal is to pass in two values, `val` and `fac` and output a list of the form `[val1, val1*fac,val1*fac*fac...]` but it doesn't work.

```
 gm :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
 gm val fac = let j=0 in
[ if (x==val) then x else if (x==(val+1)) then k else j 
| x <- [val..], let k = val*fac, let j = fac*k]
```

For example if I called `gm 2 3` I should get the result `[2,6,18,54,162...]` but what I get is `[2,6,18,18,18...]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel like you're trying to translate an imperative algorithm directly to Haskell. The standard way of defining such infinite lists is by using laziness and recursion:

```
gm val fac = val : gm (val * fac) fac
```

If you want to use a list comprehension:

```
gm val fac = [val * fac^i | i <- [1..]]
```

Comment: That helped. I forgot about the "^" operator. that was all I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do:

```
gm' val fac = iterate (*fac) val
```

Output:

```
*Main> take 5 $ gm' 2 3
[2,6,18,54,162]
```

The issue with your approach is that you list comprehension can contain only three values, `val, k, j`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer why your code doesn't work, remember that there are not mutable variables in list comprehensions. This table shows how your list is getting generated as `x` progresses through the values `val`, `val+1`, ...

```
  x    k        j                   x == val? x == val+1? element
--------------------------------------------------------- -------
val    val*fac  fac*k = val*val*fac True      False       val         (x)
val+1  val*fac  fac*k = val*val*fac False     True        val*fac     (k)
val+2  val*fac  fac*k = "           False     False       val*val*fac (j)
val+3  val*fac  fac*k = "           False     False       val*val*fac (j)
...
```

So you can see that `k` and `j` don't change, because they are defined in terms of constants `val` and `fac`.

Here is a suggestion for constructing your list the Haskell way. First construct this sequence:

```
[ 1, fac, fac*fac, fac*fac*fac, ...]
```

and then apply `map (val*)` to it.

To generate the powers sequence, there are a couple of approaches:

1) It's the list of iterates of the `(*fac)` function. That is, define:

```
f x = fac*x
```

Then the powers list is:

```
[ 1, f 1, f (f 1), f (f (f 1)), ... ]
```

and this means you can use the `iterate` function from the Prelude.

2) Note that the tail of the powers sequence is `map (*fac)` of the sequence. Therefore, you can write:

```
powers x = 1 : map (*x) (powers x)
```

This is essentially the same as (1), but sometimes it is easier to spot a relationship between a sequence and its tail.